# Angular 4 drop-down menu using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, drop-down-menu

I am having trouble getting a drop-down menu working in angular 4 using bootstrap.  I've followed a few different response found here but nothing has worked. The main main menu item shows but no drop appears. I also get no errors logged anyway.  I have included the latest version of the code I have.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the application component's HTML

```
<app-header ></app-header>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the app-header html code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a routerLink="/" class="navbar-brand">NEMO</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" >

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/file-restore" *ngIf="! newHireService.isNewHireMode">File Restore</a></li>

                <li class="menu-item dropdown"  >
                    <a style="cursor: pointer;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Reports<span class="caret" ></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="menu-item dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Level 1</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="menu-item ">
                                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="menu-item dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Level 2</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

my .angular-cli.json files has the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "nemo-ui"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
            "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "styles.css"
       ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is with your angular-cli code. You placed jquery.min.js at the css block and you also didn't load the bootstrap script.

This is how that part of your angular-cli sholuld look like:

```
   "styles": [
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "styles.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
    ],
```

Comment: This solved the problem.  I have +1 the answer but it will not record because I'm new here.